# How could a liquid have a rotation power while the dextrogyre or levogyre molecules are *randomly* organised in the liquid?

Tags: optics, physical-chemistry, polarization

Let's consider a liquid that contains either dextrogyre or levogyre molecules, but only a highly preponderance of one of them.

Since the molecules are randomly oriented in the liquid, how is it possible to have a net rotation power of the liquid since the various angular orientations of the molecules should cancel out the effect of the light rotation ?

Comment: Assuming you mean "only one sort" (and even a preponderance of one) you might look here https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/6271/48509 and here https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/15503/how-do-optically-active-compounds-rotate-plane-polarized-light

Comment: @Alchimista : thank you very much. Yes I was meaning only one sort of them (I'm not fluent in english). Thank you. I will look at your very useful links.